# not able to find log file in pentaho data integration

Tags: windows, logging, pentaho, kettle

As per the suggestions while searching this on google people are saying i may find log file on this particular location on windows machine, but i am unable to find the same,

> C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Local Settings\Temp

The log file names will be in the form **spoon_UNIQUE_ID.log**

at this perticular location i am able to see .kettle folder but no log file,

can some-body tell me what is missing,

Note : I am familiar that using kitchen.bat and pan.bat i can specify the location and file name and generate the log i want to know through spoon.bat only

Answer (score 3):

You can try checking **%TEMP%** directory on Windows machine. In my case, it is set to "C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Temp" and Spoon log files are created at same location with names as **spoon_UNIQUE_ID.log**